# Why won't this while loop exit after a "0" is entered?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying to insert user input into a list until the user enters '0'. Right now, it won't exit out of the while loop once I enter `0`.

Here's my code:

```
num_array = []
inputnum = raw_input('Please enter a number: ')
num_array.append(inputnum)
while inputnum != 0:
    inputnum = raw_input('Please enter a number: ')
    num_array.append(inputnum)
for i in range(len(num_array) - 1):
    print(num_array[i] + ' + ')
print(num_array[total - 1] + ' = ' + sum(num_array))
```

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string `'0' != 0`.

Comment: I think someone learnt PHP before learning Python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
while inputnum != '0':
```

because the raw_input function returns a string, not integer. However, if your input_num needs to be an integer then follow the above solution.

Comment: As said above, raw_input returns a string '0'.

Comment: Could you add some explanation? Code-only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. It was a mistake assuming my answer was intuitive

Answer (score 1):

Try check:

```
num_array = []
#  raw_input return value as string,int convert it to string.
inputnum = int(raw_input('Please enter a number: '))
num_array.append(inputnum)
#  earlier check for string '0' to interger 0 so the condition returned true but now int() converted inputnum to integer.
while inputnum != 0:
    inputnum = int(raw_input('Please enter a number: '))
    num_array.append(inputnum)
for i in range(len(num_array) - 1):
    print("%d +" % num_array[i])
#  sum() gave exception because earlier num_array had string type but int() converted all the value to integer.  
print("%d = %d" % (num_array[len(num_array) - 1],sum(num_array)))
```